# Getting remote UDP peer address and port using getpeername()?

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp

Will getpeername() return the IP address info of the remote UDP peer ?
I suspect that it is not going to work as it requires connection.

Please confirm whether getpeername() can be used to get the remote UDP peer address.

Answer (score 1):

If a UDP socket isn't connected there is no peer. So there can't be a peer name.

And if it is connected, you already know who you connected it to.

Comment: What do you mean by "connected" here ?
UDP packets are discrete packets. Any number of programs can send UDP message to UDP server. How can we say that a particular program/client is connected ?